# Error on insert: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, contact-form

When I run this code, it returns an error. I'm trying to get the data from my input form to my database

This is the table schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students] (
  [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [Name]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
  [Email]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
  [Password] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('"+TextBox1.Text+ "','" +TextBox2.Text+ "','" +TextBox3.Text+ "','" +TextBox4.Text+"')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: If your table has more than 4 columns, you need to include the columns that the values correlate to. I don't like to cite w3schools as a source, but they have a short and concise example of [how to write an INSERT statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) both ways; including the specific columns and the way you're doing it without the columns.

Comment: Please provide table definition! Otherwise re-write your insert statement to "INSERT INTO reg (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES ('"+TextBox1.Text+ "','" +TextBox2.Text+ "','" +TextBox3.Text+ "','" +TextBox4.Text+"')" and finally user parameteres.

Comment: worth mentioning you're wide open to sql injection

Comment: use Parameters and change your Insert command declare the exact columns you want to `INSERT INTO` show us the table schema.. also do some basic google searches on how to construct a proper Insert command

Comment: who is `Guy` by the way..?

Comment: Ammar you can probably get this question taken off hold and turn it into a useful resource for future readers by editing the question and adding in the definition for your SQL table.  Your question is getting downvoted because without knowing what the table looks like it's impossible to know for certain what the issue is.

Comment: You have SQL Injection. Imagine what happens if somebody types '); DROP TABLE [Students];--

Comment: As i said I'm just working local and I'm still new in all this c# stuff that's why I'm here to get some help and feedback maybe - but thanks

Answer (score 4):

By saying `INSERT INTO` without listing the names of the fields you wish to insert into SQL is assuming that you are inserting a value for every field in the row.  So, if your table has more than four columns you will get that error.

If that is the issue, then you just need to specify which fields you are inserting, i.e. you need an insert statement in this format:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway')
```

Example above [from here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

It would however be better to use a parametrised query.